# Replicate git push -m "commit message" with a different command in shell

Tags: git, function, shell

When I push a commit in to git repository, i need some validations to be happening in the commit message. How do i mimic "git push" command with some other?

For example have a function in bash profile which gets invoked when i type git push?
How to have a function in bash profile which can contain space in between function name?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to do this. You can create git hooks for `pre-commit`, `commit-msg`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> When I push a commit in to git repository, i need some validations to be happening in the commit message.

I would assume you mean when you just commit locally, you want to validate the commit message.
You can do that using Git hooks on the client easily. More specifically you could use a `commit-msg` hook.
Here's a good tutorial from the official Git book explaining the process: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_client_side_hooks_2

I imagine your case is similar to what they state in the tutorial:

> The answer to this dilemma is to provide some client-side hooks that users can run to notify them when they’re doing something that the server is likely to reject.
>
> For example have a function in bash profile which gets invoked when i type git push? How to have a function in bash profile which can contain space in between function name?

I'm not sure what you mean with that, but I suspect you may struggle with Git aliases executing some more complex than a shortcut.

You could use `!` to run a shell script. Here's an example which you can put in our `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    # Log commits authored by me
    mylog = !git log --author=\"$(git config user.name)\"

    # Find branches containing commit
    fb = "!f() { git branch -a --contains $1; }; f"
```